# rosserial error when publishing IMU data

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when I try to use an Arduino to publish data from an IMU:

```
balto@T510:~$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
    [INFO] [WallTime: 1364421432.288265] ROS Serial Python Node
    [INFO] [WallTime: 1364421432.288485] Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB0 at 57600 baud
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
    [INFO] [WallTime: 1364421434.987086] Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes
    [INFO] [WallTime: 1364421434.987635] Setup publisher on /imu/data [sensor_msgs/Imu]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/balto/catkin_ws/install/lib/rosserial_python/serial_node.py", line 79, in <module>
        client.run()
      File "/home/balto/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 393, in run
        self.callbacks[topic_id](msg)
      File "/home/balto/catkin_ws/install/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 99, in handlePacket
        m.deserialize(data)
      File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sensor_msgs/msg/_Imu.py", line 196, in deserialize
        raise genpy.DeserializationError(e) #most likely buffer underfill
    genpy.message.DeserializationError: unpack requires a string argument of length 72
```

Any ideas what would cause this error?  Thank you in advanced.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59414/rosserial-error-when-publishing-imu-data/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2013-03-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message was too large for to published.  Created my own message just like the imu message but without the covariance matrices.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-05-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anas Alhashimi](https://answers.ros.org/users/10201/anas-alhashimi/) on 2015-11-20**:
hello Tony,
I am facing exactly the same problem. But I could not fix it in Fuerte any suggestion?
did you used the same rawimu.h used in hector slam so i can use it directly?